# List view Items Click Event

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

i am working on a Project, in which i have some data in list view and open button outside the list view through which i can open the data selected in the list view, ("for example I've user Personal Info in List view and i have a button named "Open" outside the list view so that i can Open and Modify the selected data Data ") , now problem is arising when i haven't selected any of the column in the list view and when i click on Open key then the Program should given a exception that "Please Select At least one Column to open " , my code of the UserlistForm is given below through which I've opened and navigated to the other form

frmUserList.cs Code:

```
  private void btnOpen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            int UserID;
            string sql;

            UserID = Convert.ToInt32(lvUsers.SelectedItems[0].Text.ToString());

            sql = "";                   
            sql += "SELECT * FROM UserLogin WHERE UserLogin.UserId = "+ UserID +"";


            SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection();
            SqlCommand rs = new SqlCommand();
            SqlDataReader sdr = null;
            clsConnection clsCon = new clsConnection();


            clsCon.fnc_ConnectToDB(ref cn);

            //rs = new SqlCommand();
            rs.Connection = cn;
            rs.CommandText = sql;
            sdr = rs.ExecuteReader();

            this.Close();

            frmUserBio frm = new frmUserBio(ref sdr);
            frm.Show();
            //while (sdr.Read())
            //{
            //    //strLogin = sdr.GetString(sdr.GetOrdinal("LogIn"));

            //}
            sdr.Close();
            rs = null;
            cn.Close();

        }
```

now i want to know such kind of event or anything through which i can check weather the data or any of the column is selected or not just like

```
if (// something through which i can check weather any of the column is selected or not)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Please Select At least one Column");
                }
```

Please Tell me how to do this thing... :) Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try checking on `ListView.SelectedItems`-property, if you haven't selected any items, it will be an empty collection...

```
if (listView.SelectedItems.Count == 0)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Please Select At least one Column");
}
```

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.selecteditems.aspx):

> A ListView.SelectedListViewItemCollection that contains the items that are selected in the control. If no items are currently selected, an empty ListView.SelectedListViewItemCollection is returned.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(listView1.SelectedItems.Count == 0)
{
  MessageBox.Show("Please Select At least one Column");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(listView1.SelectedItems.Count == 0)
{
  MessageBox.Show("Please Select At least one Column");
}
```